# Adding cookies in jQuery .slideToggle

Tags: jquery, cookies, slidetoggle

I have a simple .slideToggle function in my project, which is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.example5').show().before('<a class="blocks-hide">Show/Hide</a>');
    $('div.blocks-hide').click(function() {
        $('.example5').slideToggle(250);
        $('div.blocks-hide').toggleClass('blocks-show'); 
        return false;
    });
});
```

And now I want to use [cookies plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/files/jquery.cookie.js.txt) with  this function. I want the browser to remember whether I had clicked the ".blocks-hide" link when I visited the webpage previously, and collapse/expand ".example5" accordingly. But heck, I don't know how to use cookies plugin.. Please help me guys. I'm very new to JS.

Comment: -1: "I don't know how to use cookies plugin." Then find out! (Read documentation.)

Comment: You're right Chris, but the problem is "I'm very new to JS".. I didn't create the above code, I found  a tutorial for that. I'm not a developer by profession or passion, but at this time I'm onto an urent project (for myself), and so I'm seeking help here with what I'm bad at. :)

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't here to teach you programming or JavaScript; it's here to help you with specific problems when you at least have a basic grasp of programming and what you're trying to do. And if you had that, the documentation would be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Check for *blocks-show* class after click event(at the end) :

**Edit** : Typo - changed *block-show* to *blocks-show*

```
if($('.blocks-hide').hasClass('blocks-show')){
    $.cookie('toggleState', 'open');   
} else {
    $.cookie('toggleState', 'close');
}
```

after this, just check for cookie content at $(document).ready() by :

```
if($.cookie('toggleState') == 'open') {
    $('.example5').show();
}
```

and, since I figured out you haven't configured blocks-hide/blocks-show to appear when they should(when *blocks-show* is true, there is no category viw, which should be the opposite), a better if-else check would be:

```
if($('.example5').css('display') != 'none){
    $.cookie('toggleState', 'open');   
} else {
    $.cookie('toggleState', 'close');
}
```

Use the one checking for CSS property display.

Comment: Doesn't work yet. Although I can see a cookies set in my browser with the content "close"..

Comment: You can have a look over here http://redesign.techit.in . Site takes time to load, because it isn't optimised yet. Script's in the head tag. And btw, I am using ".blocks-hide" only to give a background image to the link, I added a ToggleClass event on Click event so that the background image of the link can be changed when clicked each time. One more thing, the script is used right below featured gallery of the homepage, called "Category blocks".

Comment: Dude!! it's just a typo I made, and you didn't notice. First line would be : if($('.blocks-hide').hasClass(' **blocks** -show')).. Check the comment again - Edited

Comment: great... i didn't notice that!

Comment: use the if-else on .example5, rather than checking for class "blocks-show". See above